# NSArray elements which have from NSSet not displayed in TableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, nsarray

I have NSArray elements which is implemented from NSSet and if i tried to display the elements in Table View Cell i'm getting BAD ACCESS issue at tableView numberOfRowsInSection part.Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];




jsonurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sample.net/products.php"];//NSURL

jsondata=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:jsonurl];//NSString
jsonarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];//NSMutableArray

self.jsonarray=[jsondata JSONValue];

array=[jsonarray valueForKey:@"post_title"];

set = [NSSet setWithArray:array];//NSMutableSet
array=[set allObjects];//NSArray


NSLog(@"%@",array);



}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)  
{        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];



}
// Configure the cell...

cell.textLabel.text = [self.array objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];    
return cell;
}
```

Kindly help please.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are not allocating the array. You are setting an autoreleased object to that array that's why you are getting this error.

Replace `array=[set allObjects];` with `array=[[set allObjects] retain];`

Comment: but i have one problem if i select any cell the next viewcontroller is not getting loaded..

Comment: here is my code for that - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    
     ViewController *detailViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
    
}

Comment: @VishnuPrasath: What happens, when you try this ? Is there any errors on the console ?

Comment: @VishnuPrasath: please check `detailViewController` and `navigationController` is there. I think `navigationController` is nil.

Comment: Please put break point in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath and check the values. Or put NSLog(@"%@ %@",detailViewController ,self.navigationController ); before pushing the view. Please check the console too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14782/discussion-between-vishnu-prasath-and-midhun-mp)

Comment: @VishnuPrasath: please check this link:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7QIlDU2stU&feature=related

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you are setting your instance variables to autoreleased objects without retaining them.

Either make "set" and "array" retained properties and do

```
self.set = [NSSet setWithArray:self.array];

// This is already a bit weird... If the set is made from the array, the array will be unchanged.
self.array = [self.set allObjects];
```

Or just retain them:

```
set = [[NSSet setWithArray:array] retain];
```

etc.

Since setWithArray and allObjects return autoreleased objects, you are left with dangling pointers as soon as you leave the scope of viewDidLoad.

Comment: but i have one problem if i select any cell the next viewcontroller is not getting loaded..

Comment: here is my code for that - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller. ViewController *detailViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]; // ... // Pass the selected object to the new view controller. [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES]; [detailViewController release]; }